# search in array object nested ts

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

I have arrays of this object:

```
const equipmentSchema = new Schema({
   country: { type: String, required: true },
   uf: { type: String, required: true },
   state: { type: String, required: true },
   city: { type: String, required: true },
   cp: { type: String },
   alias: { type: String },
   address: { type: String },
   location: { type: String },
   vendor: { type: String },
   hostname: { type: String, required: true, uppercase: true },
   type: { type: String, required: true },
   model: { type: String, required: true },
   cards: [{
       model: { type: String, required: true },
       slot: {type: String, required: true },
       typePort: { type: String, required: true },
       ports: [{
           numberPort: { type: Number, required: true },
           connector: { type: String },
           status: { type: String, required: true },
           speedCircuit: { type: String },
           serviceType: { type: String },
           network: { type: String },
           connectedTo: { type: String },
           customerName: { type: String },
           addressCustomer: { type: String },
           lelisID: { type: String },
           requester: { type: String },
           dateRequester: { type: Date },
           carrier: { type: String }
       }]
   }]
```

I don't have any idea how can i search by "Customer name" and retrive all object. (I'm using Angular2)

Thanks for all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.filter(o => 
    !!o.cards.find(c => 
        !!c.ports.find(p => 
            p.customerName === "Marek")))`

To scan nested arrays you can use **find** which will return first matching element or **undefined** if there's no match in your array. Filter expects function which will return boolean so to improve readability we cast object or undefined to boolean using **!!**. Because we're filtering on outer array, entire objects will be returned.